# Using sed to edit html

Tags: html, linux, unix, sed

In Linux, execute the following command to download the "First Monday" article:

```
wget -O first_monday.html http://www.uic.edu/htbin/cgiwrap/bin/ojs/index.php/fm/article/view/3156/2747
```

Use sed and regular expressions to edit first_monday.html as follows:

Remove empty/blank paragraphs, if any. (HTML paragraph starting tag is `<p>` and ending tag is `</p>`)

```
<p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

A paragraph is empty if there is nothing or has only spaces or tabs in between `<p>` and `</p>`

Remove all images (In HTML, images are defined with the `<img>` tag. Example:

```
<img src="html5.gif" alt="The official HTML5 Icon">
```

The resulting file should still be a valid HTML file, displayable in a standard web browser. 
For your answer, copy/paste the commands you used to answer this question.  For example, if you used a command similar to

```
sed -iback -e 's|<p>[[:space:]]*</p>||g' first_monday.html
```

then you would paste that command as well as any others you used in the answer for this field.

Comment: Don't use sed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Smells like homework. What have you tried? What's your question?

Comment: @choroba I tired sed -iback -e 's|<p>[[:space:]]*</p>||g' first_monday.html but saw no difference

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can remove empty paragraph tag using following [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command

```
sed -i 's|<p>[[:space:]]*</p>||g' first_monday.html
```

Next, your image tags can also be removed same way using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command as follows;

```
sed -i 's|<img /*>||g' first_monday.html
```